# How to share long text content in Whatsapp using Ionic

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have strange problem with WhatsApp sharing. When I am sharing it doesn't share full text. Text is arround 1000 lines but not share all lines!! What is the problem? Is there any limit to text? I am using this plugin : https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

```
sharedata() {
    let msgToShare = '*Data1*' + '\r\n' + this.maindata.d1+ '\r\n' + this.maindata.d2+ '\r\n\n' + '*Data2*' + this.maindata.d3+ '\r\n\n' + '*Data3*' + this.maindata.d4+ '\r\n\n' + '*Data4' + this.maindata.d5+ '\r\n\n' + '*Data5*' + this.maindata.d6;
    console.log(msgToShare);
    var options = {
        message: msgToShare
    }

    var onSuccess = function (result) {
        console.log("Share completed? " + result.completed); // On Android apps mostly return false even while it's true
        console.log("Shared to app: " + result.app); // On Android result.app is currently empty. On iOS it's empty when sharing is cancelled (result.completed=false)
    }

    var onError = function (msg) {
        console.log("Sharing failed with message: " + msg);
    }
    window['plugins'].socialsharing.shareWithOptions(options, onSuccess, onError);
}
```

Comment: Will you please share your code whatever you have tried?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Can you please provide what have you done for it.

Comment: I have update my issue with full details, Can you check pleas?

Answer (score 0):

Whatsapp has limit of number of characters in a single message and it's 65536 that is 2^16. So make your mathematics to calculate text length.

---

1. To be sure that its not plugin/your code problem, share long text via mail.  If everything is ok, therefore its Whatsapp restrictions and you have nothing to do with that but split long text to chunks and send several messages
2. Copy long text manually and paste in Whatsapp, I believe you will get the same behavior

Comment: So how others share more text? How read more option works in WhatsApp?

Comment: I have added  issue here too : https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues/874

Comment: Who others? split it to several messages

Comment: Like this : https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-JIVfhvUct9k/V7WQFgNIb-I/AAAAAAAABWE/E8whA2XOfVkHqg20t2g4X9QEj17V4l2gQCLcB/s1600/how%2Bto%2Badd%2BRead%2BMore%2Blink%2Bon%2BWhatsApp%2Bmessages.jpg

Comment: Please take a look on my update. In Whatsapp `see more` is included in 65536 chars.

Comment: 1) Yeah, I can share all lines on Twitter or other networks.
2) Manually works fine but If manually, then plugin is useless for long lines!

Comment: @HarinderSingh so its not problem of your code or plugin. `SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin` is open source and you can check that plugin sends everything to whatsapp.

Comment: How can we send message to whatsapp like see more option!! Any idea?

Comment: @HarinderSingh you can't. This is what you see on other side of whatsapp.

Comment: Any other way without do it manually ? I have count message characters, They are only 5000 approx. I think they are counting white space too. What do you think?